# How to fill the text box with value of a column of a GridView row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In the grid I have following columns

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="select to pay">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_OnCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </ItemTemplate>            
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="Reference" HeaderText="Invoice" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">           
    </asp:BoundField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="ChargedDate" HeaderText="Date of charge" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}">            
    </asp:BoundField>

     <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" HeaderStyle-                      HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> 
       </asp:BoundField>    
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount applied">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayAmount" Width="80px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

[image]
Please tell, In the grid if I chose a check box, the amount value should be displayed in the textbox of the same row. If I checked more than one check boxes the values should displayed in the text boxes of related check boxes/ Rows.  the sum should be displayed in the textbox below the grid. What should I need to write under "OnSelect_CheckedChanged" event?

Comment: I would use the `FooterTemplate` for your total row. What means "total amount of the same row"? Are there multiple values in one row?

Comment: Hi Tim, I mean if I chose the check box of first column, It should display the amount in the textbox of last column. if I checked more than one check boxes those amounts should be displayed in the related text boxes their rows and sum should be displayed at the Bottom text box. please help me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm still confused about what you're asking.  I only see one CheckBox in your code, but you're talking about checking more than one.  Is the other checkBox going to be in our grid, or outside it?  Maybe you could add some kind of example (a screen shot, or some more markup, or just a clearer written explanation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At OnCheckedChanged event it should be

```
protected void chkSelect_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String czTemp = String.Empty;
    GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent;
    GridViewRow footer = grdDues.FooterRow; 

    TextBox txtAmount = (TextBox)gr.Cells[3].FindControl("txtPayAmount");
    TextBox txtAmountPaid = (TextBox)footer.FindControl("txtAmountPaid");
    double dbTotalAmt = Convert.ToDouble(txtAmountPaid.Text.Replace("$","").ToString());
    if( ((CheckBox)sender).Checked )
    {
        txtAmount.Enabled = true;
        czTemp = grdDues.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text.ToString();
        txtAmount.Text = czTemp.ToString();
        dbTotalAmt = dbTotalAmt + Convert.ToDouble(czTemp);
    }
    else
    {
        txtAmount.Enabled = false;
        czTemp = grdDues.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text.ToString();
        dbTotalAmt = dbTotalAmt - Convert.ToDouble(czTemp);
        txtAmount.Text = "0.00";
    }
    txtAmountPaid.Text = dbTotalAmt.ToString("C");}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="TotalAmount" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="select to pay">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_OnCheckedChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("TotalAmount", "{0:#,##0.00}")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount applied">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayAmount" Width="80px" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="80px" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

ASPX.CS

```
public partial class Forum : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.ID = "GridView1";
        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gv.ShowFooter = true;
        gv.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "TotalAmount" };

        TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
        tf.ItemTemplate = new MyCustomTemplate();
        gv.Columns.Add(tf);

        BoundField bf = new BoundField();
        bf.DataField = "TotalAmount";
        gv.Columns.Add(bf);

        tf = new TemplateField();
        tf.ItemTemplate = new MyCustomTextTemplate();
        tf.FooterTemplate = new MyCustomFooterTextTemplate();
        gv.Columns.Add(tf);

        this.form1.Controls.Add(gv);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = form1.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dynamic data = new[] {
        new { ID = 1, Name = "Name1",TotalAmount= 10},
        new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2",TotalAmount= 20},
        new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3",TotalAmount= 30},
        new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4",TotalAmount= 40},
        new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5",TotalAmount= 50}
    };

            gv.DataSource = data;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic data = new[] {
               new { ID = 1, Name ="Name_1"},
               new { ID = 2, Name = "Name_2"},
               new { ID = 3, Name = "Name_3"},
               new { ID = 4, Name = "Name_4"},
               new { ID = 5, Name = "Name_5"}
           };


    }



}

public class MyCustomTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.ID = "chkSelect";
        cb.AutoPostBack = true;
        cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cb_CheckedChanged);
        container.Controls.Add(cb);
    }

    protected void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (sender as CheckBox).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        TextBox txtPayAmount = row.FindControl("txtPayAmount") as TextBox;

        if ((sender as CheckBox).Checked)
        {
            txtPayAmount.Text = Convert.ToString((row.Parent.Parent as GridView).DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["TotalAmount"]);
        }
        else
        {
            txtPayAmount.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        int TotalAmount = 0;

        foreach (GridViewRow rowv in (row.Parent.Parent as GridView).Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = rowv.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                TotalAmount += Convert.ToInt32((row.Parent.Parent as GridView).DataKeys[rowv.RowIndex]["TotalAmount"]);
            }
        }

        GridViewRow rowf = (row.Parent.Parent as GridView).FooterRow;

        ((TextBox)rowf.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text = TotalAmount.ToString();
    }
}

public class MyCustomTextTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        TextBox cb = new TextBox();
        cb.ID = "txtPayAmount";
        container.Controls.Add(cb);
    }


}

public class MyCustomFooterTextTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        TextBox cb = new TextBox();
        cb.ID = "TextBox1";
        container.Controls.Add(cb);
    }


}
```

Comment: What if the data in the grid is dynamically generated.

Comment: Yes, I am filling the grid dynamically from the database using the c# code. And then process the functionality as I explained above. From the above code you mentioned I am not getting any values in the variables like TotalAmount.

Comment: I have updated above code snippet. Please check it and let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks Jayesh for your help. I got some simplified solution which I posted below and marked as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You mean there are rows in the grid with one check box and a text box columns? Each row contain a checkbox and other columns values as mentioned in the code and a Text box? Please attach a image/ screenshot.

Comment: Yes there are rows in the grid, each row contain a checkbox and other values like Invoice, Date, Amount. If I select a checkbox of a grid row I should display the amount in the textbox of the same row. if I select more than one rows (Check boxes) I should display their amount values in their related rows's Text box and All the sum of Textboxes should be shown at the bottom Text box.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to do it using javascript then please try this.

```
       $(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
            calculateSum(5); // sum of 5th column
        });

        function calculateSum(colidx) {
            total = 0.0;
            $("tr:has(:checkbox:checked) td:nth-child(" + colidx + ")").each(function () {
                var Tot = ($(this).text());
                Tot = parseFloat(Tot.replace(/,/g, ''));
                total += Tot;
            });
            $("#<%=txtTotalAmt.ClientID %>").val(total).toFixed(2);
        }
    });
```